# Recording a tod_training bag

Tags: ros, kinect, object-recognition, tod-training

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Does anyone know how to record a tod_training bag file. I have some unsuccessful attempts. I don't know why my bag files are not valid. I changed all the topics names of my kinect output topics as
/camera_info
/image  (initial name ../rgb/image_color)
/image_mono
/points2
as my main bag file i record these topics to main.bag
In main.tf.bag
I have my tf message.
I edit config.txt having the name main

But it doesn't take the image and point cloud instances as it should be.

How can I record a tod_training bag with kinect? What are the bottlenecks?

Best regards..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9386/recording-a-tod_training-bag/) by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2011-03-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
For recording bags we have our own program - tod_training image_pcl_recorder
You can launch this for the openni by running:
roslaunch tod_training record_openni.launch bag:=`pwd`/awesome.bag interval:=0.5

It writes bag file with needed topic names.
Best regards,
Alexander.

---

Originally posted by [Alexander Shishkov](https://answers.ros.org/users/334/alexander-shishkov/) with karma: 191 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dlmypr](https://answers.ros.org/users/128/dlmypr/) on 2011-03-30**:
they moved it to tod_stub and dump_all and train all are gone. new name of the executable is model_extraction

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-24**:
This launch file is currently missing in my svn co from :https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/stacks/object_recognition/tod_training
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the image_pcl_recorder moved to tod_stub and the launch file also.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1